# Using Jenkins REST /stop on JavaScript gives me CORS

Tags: javascript, jenkins, cors

I am trying to make a function on my website to stop a running Jenkins pipeline.

I tried below,

```
let myHeaders = new Headers({
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
})
myHeaders.append("Content-Type", "application/json");
myHeaders.append("Authorization", "Basic c3RhcnNpdDpjaXNjbzEyMw==");

let requestOptions = {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: myHeaders,
  redirect: 'follow'
  mode: 'cors',
};

fetch("<my_server>/<buildNum>/stop", requestOptions)
  .then(response => response.text())
  .then(result => console.log(result))
  .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
```

This gives me an error

```
Access to fetch at '<my_server>/<buildNum>/stop' from origin
 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass
 access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. 
If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' 
to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

I added the option `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` to the header and also set the `mode` to `cors` in the `requestOptions`.

Any help, please?

Comment: cors are not request headers. they are response headers.

Answer (score 0):

The **Access-Control-Allow-Origin** must be present on the response not in the request. The Jenkins API must respond with this header to allow your request to proceed. Take a look on this plugin https://plugins.jenkins.io/cors-filter/.

Answer (score 0):

Your server should enable **CORS** for **/stop** endpoint, so the header **Access-Control-Allow-Origin** will be in the response. Check this out [CORS explanation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS)